# Mongoid Grouping by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

this is the kind of document I have:

```
{
  event_type: 'click',
  created_at: '2015-02-15 10:00:00',
  user_id: 100
}
```

I need to sum unique users per day with event_type = click.
To get something like:

```
{
  count: 320,
  date: '2015-02-15'
}

{
  count: 451,
  date: '2015-02-16'
}
```

(note the date format)

I've tried many different things I found on SO, this one almost worked for me:
[Best way to group by date with Mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384437/best-way-to-group-by-date-with-mongoid)
I just couldn't figure out how to modify it to do exactly what I need.

This is the raw query that's almost doing what I want to achieve with Mongoid:

```
db.events.aggregate([
  {$match: {event_type: 'click', created_at: {
    $gte: ISODate('2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
    $lt: ISODate('2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')
  }}},
  {$group: {
      _id: {user_id: '$user_id', account_id: '$account_id', created_at: {
           day: { $dayOfMonth: '$created_at' },
           month: { $month: '$created_at' },
           year: { $year: '$created_at'}
       }},
      'count': {'$sum': 1}
      }
  },
  {$sort: {created_at: -1}},
])
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: is your `created_at` date is ISO date or string ?

Comment: created_at is ISO date

Answer (score 2):

in mongo 2.8  [$dateToString](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) provide facility to convert ISO date to string format so below query may solve your problem

```
    db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$match": {
    "event_type": "click"
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
    "yearMonthDay": {
        "$dateToString": {
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
            "date": "$created_at"
        }
    },
    "user_id": "$user_id"
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "user_id": "$user_id",
        "date": "$yearMonthDay"
    }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.date",
    "count": {
        "$sum": "$_id.user_id"
    }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
    "date": "$_id",
    "count": "$count",
    "_id": 0
    }
})
```

In above query first group create group of date wise and user_id and second group again count sum of user_id according to date

Comment: thanks. I use v2.6 so I'll try to find a way to do something similar with the current release, and see if it works for me.

Could you explain what you did to make it work? I see you have multiple $group and $project it the query, why is that?

Comment: Any idea how I can run this raw query through Mongoid? or write it with Mongoid?

Comment: I think for more help you should check this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176855/data-type-conversion-in-mongodb`

Comment: Thanks. So no neat way to do this in v2.6? there isn't dateToString replacement?

Comment: yes there is no way directly to convert ISO date to string in version lower than 2.8 but in version 2.8 and above direct conversion using `datToString`  if you will able to upgrade your mongo to newer version then use this :)

Comment: Nice to see a solution in the latest version.

Comment: 2.8's not released yet! 2.6 is still the latest version as of Feb 2015. Also, 2.8 has been renamed to 3.0, so the next production version number after 2.6 will be 3.0.