# MongoDB group and distinct

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have an events collection, with `user_id` and `created_at` (ISO date).
I need to sum numbers of objects per-day, and only count one event of `user_id` for each day.

I got the next query working, but its counting all events for the same user for each day:

```
results = Event.collection.aggregate([
  {"$match" =>  {
    "created_at" => {
      "$gte" => start_time, "$lte" => end_time
    },
    "event_type" => "click"
  }},
  {"$group" => {
    "_id" => {
      "$concat" => [
        {"$substr" => [{"$year" => "$created_at"}, 0, 4]},
        '-',
        {"$cond" => [
           {"$lt" => [{"$month" => "$created_at"}, 9]},
           {"$concat" => ["0", {"$substr" => [{"$month" => "$created_at"}, 0, 2]}]},
           {"$substr" => [{"$month" => "$created_at"}, 0, 2]}
        ]},
        '-',
        {"$cond" => [
           {"$lt" => [{"$dayOfMonth" => "$created_at"}, 9]},
           {"$concat" => ["0", {"$substr" => [{"$dayOfMonth" => "$created_at"}, 0, 2]}]},
           {"$substr" => [{"$dayOfMonth" => "$created_at"}, 0, 2]}
        ]}
      ]
    },
    "count" => {"$sum" => 1}
  }}
])
```

I tried to combine it with the answer here:
[Mongoid Grouping by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543150/mongoid-grouping-by-date)

but it didn't work for me.

How can I make it distinct `user_id` AKA ignore multiple records of the same day for the same user?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't feel like the right answer though, I'm sure there's a better way to solve this.

Comment: If it works then it is *a* right answer even if it isn't the best answer, that's certainly better than no answer at all.

Answer (score 1):

I got this one working, I just count the users_unique array length later in the code.

```
db.events.aggregate(
  {$match: {event_type: 'click', created_at: {
    $gte: start_time,
    $lt: end_time
  }}},
  {$project: {
    user_id: $user_id,
    year: {$year: $created_at}, 
    month: {$month: $created_at},
    day: {$dayOfMonth: $created_at}
  }},
  {$group: {
       _id: {year: $year, month: $month, day: $day},
       unique_users: {$addToSet: $user_id},
       total_sessions: {$sum: 1}
  }}
)
```